# Validar espacios en blanco con Expresiones Regulares en Formularios Reactivos

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, angular7, angular6

Se supone que la expresión regular para validar espacios en blanco es "\s" sin embargo no me esta funcionando probé algo sencillo como esto : "[a]\s[a]" ( esto es solo un ejemplo, en realidad mi expresion regular es mas grande pero quiero comprobar porque no funcion el "\s"), esto debería validar que ingrese "a a" , pero me sigue tirando "invalid=true". Probe en todas las paginas donde hacen test de expresiones regulares y si funciona, pero no en Formularios Reactivos . Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
private async crearFormulario() {
  this.forma = this.fb.group({
    nombre_prod: [this.registroModel.getNombre_Prod, [Validators.pattern("[a]\s[a]")]],
  });
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-12 form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1 ">Nombre de producto</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nombre_prod" [class.is-invalid]="nombreProdIncorrecto()">
</div>
```

```js
nombreProdIncorrecto()
  {
    return this.forma.get("nombre_prod").invalid
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El regex debe de llevar `\\s` para que angular lo interprete correctamente. Debe quedar de esta manera:

```
this.formulario = fb.group({
      nombre_prod: ["", [Validators.pattern("[a]\\s[a]")]]
    });
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqrxic)

Comment: Gracias por responder, encontré también otra forma de hacerlo, q es poniendo la expresión regular sin comillas y entre dos backslash ( / / )